# Reinstalling Git on Windows

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

Git bash stopped working for me not sure if i messed up some system variables or something but when i uninstall and try to reinstall i get a series of unable to set system config errors

> Error 1
>
> [image]

> Error 2
>
> [image]

> Error 3
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's trying to access C:\\.config and is unable to. Try moving that folder our of the way and doing the install again. I think if it's not there it creates it during the install.

Comment: I tried that didn't work, i have literally tried everything i can think of over the past few days, tried clearing out every trace of git i can find but keeps telling me its unable to set system config defaults

Answer (score -1):

So I finally figured it out, Went into the registry editor and found all instances of git including the path variable and deleted them, restarted computer and reinstalled git bash successfully, I also deleted a HOME variable that I had created right before bash originally stopped working so not sure if that was a factor as well. This short video on youtube helped- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVVPWmhzYjk

Comment: Whoa, sounds like a recipe to mess up a PC. This is risky if you don't know what you're doing.